# CrystalReports DataTable Error VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, crystal-reports, datatable, dataset

I'm trying to pass all data from a DB to a report: but I get an error (The report has no tables)

```
Dim sqlConn As String = "SELECT (SUM(item_selldetail * item_quantity )/ 100 * 12) AS isv_report," & _
                    " (SUM( item_selldetail * item_quantity ) - (SUM(item_selldetail * item_quantity )/ 100 * 12)) " & _
                    " AS capital_report,SUM( item_selldetail * item_quantity ) AS total_report  FROM qa_items;"
                Dim objDataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlConn, objConn)

                ' DataSet
                Dim ds As New DataSet

                ' llenar el DataSet
                objDataAdapter.Fill(ds)


                Dim mireporte As New ReportDocument()

                mireporte.Load("C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Proyectos\Quickadmon\Quickadmon\Reportes\report_capital_rpt.rpt")

                mireporte.SetDataSource(ds)

                Me.capitalreport_viewer_capital_report.ReportSource = mireporte
```

Anyone have any idea what I can do?

Comment: More details needed, sample output, whats the error.  BTW your variable name `sqlConn` is very misleading.  To me sqlConn means sql connection, when in fact sqlConn in your case is an sql string that might be a SQLCommand call.

Comment: When I've done this, I've created an XML file in conjuction with a DataTable/DataReader object and pointed an ADO.NET connection to that in Crystal (it will allow you to lay out the fields on the report).  Then from your .Net program you can pass that DataTable in.  To me it looks like you're returning one recordset in that DataSet.  Give me a few and I'll type up a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I need to do this programmatically, without using a wizard, occupied a basic example of how to select some fields from a table and display it in a report viewer. I am somewhat confused programmatically all about it.

 What I also avoid is having to use absolute paths to files xml or rpt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code here , try to dolike this

```
    sql = "SELECT Product_id,Product_name,Product_price FROM Product"
    Dim dscmd As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet1
    dscmd.Fill(ds, "Product")
    cnn.Close()

    Dim objRpt As New CrystalReport1
    objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(1))
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

If you need full source code :

http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/crystal_report_from_sql_query_string.htm

merca.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've done in the past.

1.)  Create an ADO.NET (XML) Connection in Crystal.  You will need to provide a path to an XML file to do this, the XML file will include the DataTable (or DataReader's) schema.  It would look something like this (the *x0020* represents a space in a field if you have one, see http://www.blakepell.com/Blog/?p=14 for more details on that):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <people>
      <first_x0020_name>
      <last_x0020_name>
      <phone>
  </people>
```

2.)  Set your data source like you did, in my wrapper code I had something like this where I was setting it from properties on the wrapper:

```
    If _dataReader IsNot Nothing Then
        report.SetDataSource(_dataReader)
    End If

    If _dataTable IsNot Nothing Then
        report.SetDataSource(_dataTable)
    End If
```

3.)  Put it in your viewer control (or export it which is usually what I do since I'm generating the PDF output from it).

```
    report.Export()
```

If this doesn't work for you, then post the specific stack trace and exception that you receive whenever you do this so we can troubleshoot it better. ;)

Comment: There is any way to import the XML file without using absolute paths and do THROUGH programmatically, without reporting wizard? Thanks

Comment: The XML file is something you would create and would live in the same directory with your report (I had to create mine by hand).  It's basically a schema that tells Crystal what fields you're going to have available so you can lay them out on your report.